# Embedding of the hyperbolic 3-space into the 4-dimensional Euclidean space

Tags: partial-differential-equations, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, isometry

Is there a global isometric immersion of the 3-dimensional hyperbolic space into the 4-dimensional Euclidean space?

(I am aware of Hilbert's theorem, but that is on the embedding of $H^2$ in $E^3$. I have also seen the thesis of Brander 2003, but there I could not find an answer to my question. Furthermore, other posts in stackexchange do not refer to $H^3$ in $E^4$.)

Comment: Did you have a look in this [survey article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.1875.pdf)? I don't think such an embedding is possible. A Riemannian $n$-manifold of constant negative sectional curvature cannot be isometrically immersed in $E^{2n−2}$.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know this survey.